# Como Instalar Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle en Windows Server 2012R2x64

Tags: .net, windows, oracle

alguien sabe como puedo instalar Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle en Windows Server 2012R2x64, ya lei por todo lado que esto no se puede porque:

> Este proveedor ya esta obsoleto y sin soporte
>
> No existe una versión para x64
>
> Es recomendable utilizar los proveedores de ORACLE
>
> Un millón de razones mas .

Bueno el dilema es que tengo un sistema web gigante que utiliza MSDAORA y debe ser migrado a WS2012R2, en la cadena de conexion cambio el provedor a ORAOLEDB.ORACLE, pero en lo que va de las pruebas con este cambio de cadena solo funciona como un 70% de los códigos que interactuan con la BD.

El punto es que como es un sistema gigantes, si sigo con el camino de cambiar de proveedor las pruebas demorarían mas y se tendría mucho mucho mucho código que modificar, Y ESA NO ES LA IDEA. Lo que se quiere hacer es migrar la aplicación a un WS2012R2x64 si es posible con 0% de modificación de código, y para esto quiero de alguna manera (hasta tal vez no oficial) instalar el MSDAORA el un WS2012R2x64, alguien sabe como puedo lograr realizar dicha instalación???

Saludos cordiales a todos.

Comment: Yo acabo de tener el mismo problema, en mi caso tenia que usar excel para hacer la conexión y tuve el mismo detalle, cual fue mi solución? instale Oracle Database 11g Release 2 pero en su versión de 32 bits cree su conexión odbc y santo remedio

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) estaba diseñado para plataformas x86 sobre Windows 2000, 98, ME y NT la última revisión es la 2.8 SP1 es de 05/10/2005 a partir de entonces se integraron en los sistemas operativos siguientes como Windows Data Access Components (WDAC)

Si tu base de datos esta en Oracle instala los drivers ODBC de Oracle y acceder a cualquier base de datos relacional

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-098155.html

en lugar de usar OLEDB, o ODAC:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Si tu aplicación esta en .NET utilizar al proveedor de Oracle directamente:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html