# DLL de 32 bits en windows server 2008 R2 de 64 bits

Tags: asp, regsvr32

Hola he registrado una dll de 32 bits en windows server 2008 R2 de 64 bits y se registra correctamente, incluso puedo crear el objeto, pero el momento de usar un método definido en la dll siempre me sale:

```
ADODB.Connection error '800a0e78'  
La operación no está permitida si el objeto está cerrado.
```

Estoy usando ASP clásico y la dll contiene una función que se conecta a oracle 12c por odbc ya he revisado la cadena de conexión y es correcta, en el servidor de 32 bits funciona correctamente con asp clasico y oracle 10g.

Estoy llamando la dll de la siguiente manera

```
dim objBdaPais    
set objBdaPais = Server.CreateObject("nombredll.nombrecls")
sPais = objBdaPais.nombreMetodo()
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos.

Comment: Mira que curioso es muy parecido a esta pregunta: (o algo relacionada) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24423/como-instalar-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-en-windows-server-2012r2x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente: Si conectas por ODBC, igual no lo tengas bien configurado...

En los sistemas de 64 bits tienes dos consolas para configurar los orígenes de datos ODBC. La que muestra por defecto desde el panel de control, es la de  64bits. Y lo que configures ahí no lo va a ver tu app de 32bits. Te toca configurar la conexión en la consola ODBC de 32 bits...

De ahí el mensaje de error en tu app. Porque no ha conseguido conectar

Saludos